# Can a method with arbitrary number of arguments, be called with an array?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, call

I would like to call a method which signature is

```
public void foo(Object object, Object ... objects) { }
```

and I call it like

```
Object[] objects = ...;
foo(objects);
```

as the compiler does'nt complain it seems valid, but
what happens with the first parameter in the signature? Is it `objects[0]`

Can anyone explain the `Object ... objects` parameter, what happens internal?

I can't change the method, it's from Method class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varargs are effectively a different syntax to describe arrays so in principle yes. But since you defined the first parameter explicitly you'd have to pass that separately.

The problem with vargs is that you also could not pass any parameter, i.e. an array of length 0. That's probably why you want to declare the first parameter explicitly, which is ok IMO. You just can't call it the way you want.

With your method signature the following should work:

```
foo("first");
foo("first", "second", "third");
foo("first", new String[]{"second", "third"} );
```

The problem with your definition, i.e. using `Object` is that arrays are objects as well, so the call you described above is basically like `foo("first")`.

**Edit**:

Since the method you mention is `Method.invoke(Object object, Object ... objects)` it's obvious why there are 2 parameters. The first is the target of execution, i.e. the instance the method should be invoked on, while the second is the array of parameters.

One could rewrite that signature to `Method.invoke(Object object, Object[] objects)` but calling it without first creating an array (even if of length 0) is more awkward or you'd need another method that just accepts one parameter in order to call no-arg methods.

Comment: and how would I call it as expected ?

Comment: it's not my definition it's from Method.invoke(Object object, Object ... objects)

Comment: @jam I see, in that case both parameters have a different meaning, i.e. the first would be the object to call the method on and the varargs are the optional parameters (and there might be none). In that case you should keep the array separate since the target of method execution is something different than the parameters.

Comment: okay so I missunderstood the method, I thought the method knows it's caller

Comment: @jam no, the method belongs to a class and if it's not static it would be passed the instance it's meant to operate on when being invoked. In compiled code the compiler handles that for you (adding `this` to the parameter list) while when using reflection you'd have to provide the actual instance (or `null` in case of static methods).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're just going to get one parameter in there. The second `Object...` parameter is basically optional, since an empty `Array` is also an `Array`.

The first argument in your method is of type `Object`, which means you can pass anything, including an `Array` of `Object`s

Also, the `Object...` is internally turned into an `Object[]` parameter, it's just syntactic sugar

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example that will help you understanding what's happening here:

```
-> void foo(Object object, Object ... objects) {
>>     System.out.println("First parameter: " + object);
>>     System.out.println("Second parameter: " + Arrays.toString(objects));
>> }
>>
|  Added method foo(Object,Object ...)
-> Object[] objects = new Object[]{"test1", "test2", "test3"}
|  Added variable objects of type Object[] with initial value [Ljava.lang.Object;@ae45eb6
>>
-> foo(objects)
First parameter: [Ljava.lang.Object;@ae45eb6
Second parameter: []
```

As you can see, since arrays are objects, the first parameter will get the whole array, while the second parameter gets a zero sized array. Why an empty array? Because varargs means *zero* or more objects, since the whole array was assigned to the first parameter, the second parameter gets the "zero" object.

Answer (score 0):

*Here, in your case,*

objects-array assign to First Argument of foo() that is : **Object object**

> And second Argument "Object ... objects"  refer's as a zero-size
>   Array,
>
> so, refer this example with out put might be help you in a more better
>   way,

```
  public static void main(String[] a) {
      Object[] objects = {
              new Object() , new Object(), new Object()
      };
      foo(objects);
  }

  public static void foo(Object object, Object ... objects){
      System.out.println(object.hashCode());

      System.out.println("--------------");
      System.out.println(objects.length);
       for(Object o : objects){
          System.out.println(o.hashCode());
      }

  }
```

**Out-Put :**

```
848123013
--------------
0
```